# Anonymous Type with Lambda Expressions

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm using EF, I have this query, I need to omit some information from the dataset.
I was thinking to use anonymous type so I can have control on the data emitted.

Could you help me out to rewrite this query adding only the filed `x.EventTitle` and `x.EventDateStart`?

```
db.EventCustoms
  .Where(x => x.DataTimeStart > dateTimeNow & x.DataTimeStart <= dateTimeFuture);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what `Select` is for:

```
db.EventCustoms
  .Where(x => x.DataTimeStart > dateTimeNow & x.DataTimeStart <= dateTimeFuture)
  .Select(x => new { x.EventTitle, x.EventDateStart, x.EventLocation });
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I need anonymous Type, I need to project more properties like EventTitle EventDateStart and so on. could you help me out on this? many thanks